# Find specific html element if it has no ID

Tags: javascript, html, outerhtml

I currently have an application where users can highlight a specific html element on any website. User A can share this element with the other user, where user B will open the site and see that element highlighted. The problem is how to find the element that has been highlighted on the site if it has no ID. I can copy its outerHTML and then find element by that, but I am not sure that will always work, what if a few elements have the same outerHTML.

Comment: How are the elements being highlighted? is it like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73620118/find-specific-html-element-if-it-has-no-id#:~:text=currently%20have%20an%20application

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have the feeling that you are looking for `XPath`.
XPath is basically the unique path to your DOM element.
You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

Examples of XPaths:

```
//*[@id="question"]
/html/body
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]
```

You can get the XPath on any webpage by opening up the Inspector (in the developer console), right clicking the desired element, choosing copy and then XPath from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Wow, that is really useful! Thank you so much. But I guess for example if the page gets updated then the XPath can change, is that correct? For example if one more div is added or removed. It is just painful that all elements don't have a unique id by default.

Comment: Yes true, if someone updates the design (and positions elements differently), then the XPath will change (of that element) and your code will likely break :/.